# How to serialize a file in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, json

I want to implement an asynchronous file upload for my asp.net application.  My idea is to serialize the file into JSON client-side and call a web service to reconstitute the file server-side.  My question is:

How do a read a file as binary and serialize it into JSON?  The solution can't require the use of Google Gears or "must-install" client-side technologies.  Thanks!

Comment: Are you really asking how a web page can read arbitrary files off the user's disk and send them to you?

Comment: Files already are serialized.  By definition.  What more could you want to do than a simple upload?

Comment: @S.Lott if the file is a large file I don't want the user having to wait while the page makes the round trip to the server.

Comment: What is up with people asking how to do things that are only possible with active x, and then specifically saying that active x is not acceptable?  Its been happening alot lately

Comment: @Achilles: How is the file supposed to get to the server if not by upload?  What if the user navigates away from your page while the upload is going on?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use an iframe to hide the file upload process.  You don't want to process the data in JavaScript as it will be very slow.  All you need to do is manage the user interaction.

Example: http://www.webtoolkit.info/ajax-file-upload.html

Comment: +1 for understanding and finding a solution to the poster's main problem.

Answer (score 4):

Since you can't access the file system with Javascript, I don't see how you would be able to do this, without some kind of Flash or ActiveX component installed.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to read arbitrary files from the user's hard drive in Javascript, and it never will be.

If you don't understand why, imagine what would happen if any webpage could read `%USERPROFILE%\ntuser.dat`.

---

If you want to upload a file using AJAX, you'll need to use an `IFRAME`; see [here](http://www.openjs.com/articles/ajax/ajax_file_upload/).

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of the new features in HTML5.  That's why I said **arbitrary**.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to serialize a file to upload it and JSON is not involved in file uploads.  Answers here may seem confusing because people think you are trying to upload files surreptitiously.  See Will Bickford's answer above (iframes).

Answer (score 0):

You need to ask how to accomplish the larger goal.  You have a goal in mind and you've determined that the only way to accomplish that is to serialize a file with javascript on the client (which isnt possible) and some people have tried to decipher what you really want to accomplish and suggested answers (asynch uploads etc).

Tell us what you need to accomplish and describe the task and the limits of your solution and we can help you find a solution.

Some of the things we need to know

- why are you parsing the file?
- what file sizes do you expect to encounter?
- what are you doing with the information from the file?
- why are you doing it on the web instead of a desktop app?